# How to display data for a certain period of time (day / week / month) from Mysql table in html table (php)

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I use this code to display data from MySQL table in html, but I need the ability to create html tables that will display records added in the last day / week / month.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php            
$db_host = 'localhost';         
$db_name = 'DB';         
$db_username = 'NAME';         
$db_password = 'PASS';       
$db_table_to_show = 'TABLE';         
$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) 
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());           
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)      
or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());   
mysql_set_charset("utf8");          
$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)      
or die(mysql_error());            
echo '<table id="table">';       
echo '<thead>';         
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th class="table-fandom">fandom</th>';        
echo '<th>author</th>';     
echo '<th class="table-name">name</th>';
echo '<th>size</th>';    
echo '<th class="table-status">status</th>';             
echo '<th>date</th>';       
echo '<th>tags</th>';
echo '</tr>';       
echo '</thead>';        
echo '<tbody>';         

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){       
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>' . $data['fandom'] . '</td>';    
   echo '<td>' . $data['author'] . '</td>';         
   echo '<td><a href="/goto/' . $data['url'] . '" target="_blank">' . $data['name'] . '</a><div class="menu" style="display: none;"><br> '                                             . $data['annotation'] .  '  </div></td>';       
   echo '<td>' . $data['size'] . '</td>';  
   echo '<td>' . $data['status'] . '</td>';        
   echo '<td>' . $data['date'] . '</td>';  
   echo '<td>' . $data['tags'] . '</td>';                  
   echo '</tr>';       
}       

echo '</tbody>';        
echo '</table>';         
mysql_close($connect_to_db);        
?>
```

PS Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear:
You have a lot of code which might just work. 
So is the question:
How do I get data from the database for the last day, for the last week, and for the last month?
If so: 
    select * from sometable where addsomedatefield>date_sub(now(), interval 1 days);
That will give you the last day. Similar 1 weeks or 1 months for the longer periods.

Comment: `.. WHERE date < NOW()+1 day..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i got it true you want to show data that added for specific date/time or between date/time ranges.
you should use mysql query to get data that for example last day added. you should change query:

```
$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from " . $db_table_to_show)
```

first you should save date/time for each row when it added or updated. after that you can get today date/time by PHP functions and then use it in your query.
an example:

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE `AddedDate` BETWEEN "2012-03-15" AND "2012-03-31";
```

PHP function to get date :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php